# CoreBluetooth: Range Detection in Background mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm working on an App that connects with a peripheral and needs to watch it's state.

When the App is in foreground range detection is no probleme: I just update the RSSI value from time to time and translate it in a range.

Now I would like to use the app with a CoreBluetooth Background Mode. I want to send the user a notification when the device is out of a certain range.

How can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You can start ranging your peripheral from AppDelegate.m, right after your application start on `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, set the delegate to self, and notify yourself using `UILocalNotification`.

There's example of it using `CoreLocation` instead of `CoreBluetooth` [here](https://github.com/carsonmcdonald/bluez-ibeacon/blob/master/BeaconDemo/BeaconDemo/AppDelegate.m).

Don't forget to modify your `info.Plist` for communicating in background mode.

Comment: That code sample uses "didDetermineState" to detect when the device exits the region. Is there a similar background callback for corebluetooth? I haven't been able to find it.